# name of current variable in bash pipe

Tags: bash, powershell, pipeline

In powershell `$_` is the name of the current variable being passed with pipes. What is the equivalent of this in Bash?

Let's say I want to do this

```
echo "Hi" | echo "$_"
   prints Hi
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Bash (or any other Unix shell for that matter) has no such thing.

In PowerShell, what is passed through pipes is an object. In bash, this is the output (to stdout) of the command.

The closes thing you can do is use `while`:

```
thecmd | while read theline; do something_with "$theline"; done
```

Note that `IFS` (Input Field Separator) is used, you can therefore also do:

```
thecmd | while read first therest; do ...; done
```

Comment: Yeah, I know in powershell object are passed and in bash stdout is passed in a pipe. However, I though the content of stdout could be put in a variable by default in the current session and then that variable passed so that others could use it. Any ideas why this has not been implemented? It would be something like using tee, but instead of putting the output of a command in a file it would put it in a variable (let's say $__) which can only be accessed in the current session and that can be used by other commands. I guess I could write a script to do just that.

Comment: @JuanC. you should use `A=$(echo "hi")` for this. Now you can do `echo $A`.

Comment: In case you want to pass the input without any mangling by the IFS, I propose to clear that before reading: `thecmd | while IFS='' read line; do …; done`.  That version also passes whitespace in the beginning of the read line without changing it.

Comment: Thank you, I know about several ways to do it. I was just wondering if I there was a way to save typing and  make it as simple as it is in Powershell using $_.

Comment: Powershell has an unfortunate name because it isn't really a shell nor is it like any shell language.  It's better to think of Powershell as a .NET scripting language.  In `bash`, you can access stdin with `read`, but you must realize that bash takes this input as a raw input stream.  This is unlike powershell in that powershell has the concept of the pipeline and separation of items that move through it.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix ideology there are no objects or variables. The main selling poing of Unix is that *everything is plain text*, so you just pass text from one command to another.

You can think that you just have one variable and you always use it implicitly. Your example is a bit weird, but the closest thing I can think of is `cat` command that takes whatever its input is (think about the only implicit variable) and outputs it, so

```
echo "Hi" | cat
```

prints

```
Hi
```

Comment: By the way, if you want my opinion: this sucks. Objects are much more easy to work with and they give much more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to access this value as a variable (for whatever reason) you can "fake" it using a subcommand in parenthesis as a variable name like this:

```
echo "Hi" | echo "$(cat)"
```

Comment: What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: Oh wait, works in bash, but not in zsh. Is that some dark bash magic?

Comment: How would you substitude that when you need to do something like this echo "/home/user" | echo ${pipedVar##*/}. ? This would obviously not work: echo "/home/user" | echo ${$(cat)##*/}.

Comment: @JuanC. I've replied to you in comments to another answer. Basically, if you are performing a complex task, consider writing a shell script with variables. Unlike bat-files shell scripts are usable. For this particular case it's better to do `echo "/home/user" | xargs basename`.

Comment: @kirelagin: This is by no means black bash magic ;-)  It is just the modern version of the back-quotes to get the output of a sub-command.
@Juan: No, variable substitution is not possible here.  You could of course use sth like this:  `echo "Hi" | { a=$(cat); echo "${a##*/}"; }` or (again of course) perform any modification in the subcommand, e.g.: `echo "Hi" | echo "$(cat | sed 's/x/y/g')"`

Comment: @Alfe I know what is $(). It's just that you're doing some black magic with redirecting input-output streams. That fact that it works in bash but not in zsh makes me believe that it's just a coincidence and not a POSIX-guaranteed behaviour. Why the hell, in your case, `cat`'s input will be attached to `echo`'s output? `cat` is running in a different subshell process.

Comment: Just to be clear. You second example with an expression in braces after the pipe is perfectly fine. But `echo "$(cat)"` just makes no sense (in my understanding).

Comment: @kirelagin: What is executed in a subshell will have the parent's file descriptors, so unless the shell does not close them for whatever reason, they get inherited by the child.  So, of course the output of stdin now will be read by the subcommand.  zsh seems to close the FDs before exec'ing the subcommand.  Since I'm not using zsh I cannot tell why.  And since this question is tagged `bash` and not `zsh` it also is out of scope here.  Whether or not a shell closes the FDs before forking a subshell might not be part of POSIX spec, there you are right.

Comment: @kirelagin: Off-topic, but I've noticed similar differences between `bash` and `zsh` using process substitution. It seems that `bash` evalulates the command/process substitution in the context of the pipeline job, but `zsh` processes it in the context of the shell starting the pipeline.